# Why does using SSH -X on a VPS load X11 programs so slowly?

Tags: ssh, xorg

I asked this question on StackExchange and it was suggested my question was more suitable for SuperUser.

Here it is:

I can run X11 applications on a Ubuntu VPS, but they take ages to load! I wonder if I am doing something wrong or if the problem is on the VPS.

The VPS runs Ubuntu 16.04 64 bits. It has 1 GB RAM and 1 CPU core @ 3.5 GHz.

For my setup, I installed `xauth` and edited the `/etc/ssh_config` file to set `ForwardX11` to `yes`. I edited the `/etc/sshd_config` file to set `X11Forwarding` to `yes` while the `X11DisplayOffset` is `10`.

Running `echo $DISPLAY` on the VPS shows `localhost:10.0`.

I want to connect to the VPS via SSH and run Firefox. I use `ssh -X name@vpn_ip`.

Firefox does open but each time it takes about four minutes! Then the browser greys out so it’s unusable. I thought the server might be unable to cope but a check with “top” showed that Firefox was only using 17% of the memory and around 2% of the CPU.

I acquired Firefox using `apt-get install firefox` and I also did it by downloading the 64 bit version from Mozilla. The programs that derive from both methods each took four minutes to load.

I read that using `ssh -X -C` would help as `-C` is compression. However, `-C` did not make an improvement.

Am I doing something wrong? Have I missed something? Any help is gratefully received.

Comment: X11 was never meant to be used on WAN networks. It produces too much traffic and does nothing to improve responsiveness over high-latency connections. I can’t look for reference material right now though, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing sounds about normal.

Firefox is a poor choice of application to test with, as it does a lot of client-side rendering, and pushes composited bitmaps at the server.  This is very data-heavy, even with SSH compression turned on.

I recommend sticking with programs that aren't such bandwidth hogs - `xset` should be reasonably responsive.

Answer (score 0):

toby-speight's answers is right on target.

What you missed:

A web browser has hundreds/thousands of widgets (buttons, areas, fonts). Even ignoring the data heavy ones that Tony mentioned, if every round trip from the app to your local machine takes 40 milliseconds, and you get 500 widgets pushed to your local machine, that is 20 seconds.  Bringing up a single popup menu (Like clicking on File) may push 100 widgets to your client.

Are you doing anything wrong?

Not really.  Instead of firefox, test with xterm, or gnome-terminal.  still there will be a delay, but they will be responsive where firefox or chrome is all but broken.

Alternatives!!!! :

*I* would:

1. Get used to using the command line.  It is very snappy :-)  I do 98% of my work in an xterm.
2. tmux !!
3. install vnc server
4. apt-get install tightvncserver
5. vncserver -geometry 1200x700 -interface 127.0.0.1
6. locally,
7. ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 install vnc viewer
8. vncviewer localhost:1

This will be MUCH MUCH faster and more responsive, and will be secure.